# Hibernate ManyToMany without loading objects

Tags: hibernate, jpa, persistence, many-to-many

I have a relation like

**Person <-> LivedAt <-> Address**

Where each person LivedAt possibly multiple addresses and each address could have been **LivedAt** by possibly many people.   LivedAt has attributes such as "StartDate", "EndDate" and pointers to one Person and one Address (these aren't my actual objects but just examples)

Address has a primary key, **ADDRESS_ID**

My question is,  how do I set things up so that I can create the **LivedAt** objects without having to fetch the Address objects from the database?

I already have the **ADDRESS_IDs** available from another part of my process and don't want hibernate to try to fetch the addresses.    Without hibernate available I'd just do "insert" statements but I want to do this in the hibernate manner.    I am using hibernate w annotations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Session.load()` or `EntityManager.getReference()`. This will just return a proxy to the actual Address entity, without loading anything from the database.

```
Address address = (Address) session.load(Address.class, addressId);
// address is a proxy. It will be lazy-loaded only if you invoke a method on it
```

Comment: Thanks!   When I save will hibernate be smart enough not to try to load the proxy?

Comment: Yes. The point of this method is exactly what you're trying to do: store the reference to an existing entity in another one.